# Code to use an Arduino Mega 2560 to transfer UART <-> USB to debug an other Microcontroller

Tags: arduino-mega, uart

I have the following circuit and want to use the Arduino Mega 2560 as an debugger for an other Microcontroller.
[image: circuit]

So I am looking for the code to redirect the UART input from "P17 (RX2)" to the serial USB and the data coming from the serial USB to the output of "P16 (TX2)"

Comment: Is the Arduino going to do anything other than forward serial data?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams no just forwarding

Comment: Then why use an Arduino at all? USB-to-UART bridges are much cheaper.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I know but i am not at home and here I have a Arduino Mega 2560 but no USB-to-UART bridge. So why not using the Arduino than not to be able to debug at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A very simple sketch to pass serial through looks like this:

```
void setup(){
  Serial1.begin(/*BAUD*/);
  Serial2.begin(/*BAUD*/);
}

void loop(){
  if(Serial1.available()){
    Serial2.print((char)Serial1.read());
  }
  if(Serial2.available()){
    Serial1.print((char)Serial2.read());
  }
}
```

I would advise both run at the same baud rate, otherwise you may need to do some extra buffering yourself if the arduino starts running out of buffer space. If you want to use the mega's USB connection instead of "Serial1" like your schematic, just switch "Serial1" to "Serial"